# Using Regular Expression, unable to get the complete value of second group

Tags: regex, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

In my application, I'm using [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) to rewrite the url's. This filter allows us to define the rules using either regular expression or wildcards. I'm using regular expression to match the url's. Below is the sample rule I defined,

```
<urlrewrite>
    <outbound-rule>
        <from>^/((\bjs)|(\bcss)|(\bimages))\/(.*)$</from>
        <to>www.example.com/$1/$2?q=test</to>
    </outbound-rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

With the above rule defined, I'm able to match the from url and rewritten to value configured inside `<to>` tag. The problem here is, I'm unable to get the expected value from **$2**.

For example, for URL's

- /css/login.css
- /js/login.js
- /images/logo.png

My expected output is

- www.example.com/css/login.css?q=test
- www.example.com/js/login.js?q=test
- www.example.com/images/logo.png?q=test

But I'm getting

- www.example.com/css/?q=test
- www.example.com/js/?q=test
- www.example.com/images/?q=test

Did something I'm missing in regular expression. How to retrieve the complete value of **$2** group. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming this uses PCRE, indexes are counted left to right, based on the opening bracket. So $1 has your answer, $2, $3, $4 contain the matches inside the answer, $5 should have the part you want. Similar answer here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313934/how-are-nested-capturing-groups-numbered-in-regular-expressions)

Comment: Awesome, it works like a charm. @RomanK. thanks a lot. Also link is very helpful.