# How to extract number and String in java

Tags: java

i want to extract number and add these numbers using Java and String remain same.

String as-

```
String msg="1,2,hello,world,3,4";
```

output should come like- 10,hello,world

Thanks

Comment: all are saperated by commma ?

Comment: I believe a regular expression will do the trick here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] parts = msg.split(",");
int sum = 0;
StringBuilder stringParts = new StringBuilder();
for (String part : parts) {
    try {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(part);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        stringParts.append("," + part);
    }
}
stringParts.insert(0, String.valueOf(sum));

System.out.println(stringParts.toString()); // the final result
```

Note that the above practice of using exceptions as control flow should be avoided almost always. This concrete case is I believe an exception, because there is no method that verifies the "parsability" of the string. If there was `Integer.isNumber(string)`, then that would be the way to go. Actually, you can create such an utility method. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684079/is-it-ok-to-try-catch-something-just-to-check-if-an-exception-was-thrown-or-not/).

Comment: Isn't relying on exceptions to control program flow a bad practice? Otherwise it looks like a pretty nice simplistic solution with close to no accidental complexity.

Comment: @vstoyanov there was a discussion about that specific case (with parsing numbers/date), let me find it. Generally, yes, it's a bad practice to rely on exceptions, but since there is no method to verify the parsability..

Comment: @vstoyanov http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684079/is-it-ok-to-try-catch-something-just-to-check-if-an-exception-was-thrown-or-not/3684093#3684093

Comment: for (String part : parts) please detail this statement what it does.

Comment: this is the foreach loop introduced in Java 5. It loops all elements of the array/collection

Comment: @Bozho  http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html there is a api to check , check my answer

Answer (score 5):

Break up your problem:

1. parsing into tokens
2. converting tokens into objects
3. operate on objects

Answer (score 5):

```
String pieces[] = msg.split(",");  
int sum=0;
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for(int i=0;i < pieces.length;i++){

      if(org.apache.commons.lang.math.NumberUtils.isNumber(pieces[i])){
             sb.appendpieces[i]();
      }else{
             int i = Integer.parseInt(pieces[i]));
             sum+=i;    
      }

 }
 System.out.println(sum+","+sb.);
 }
```

Comment: @Chankey yeah it was typo. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the downvote... it seems in this special case, it IS legit... but thanks for the update. +1

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple regex version:

```
/**
 * Use a constant pattern to skip expensive recompilation.
 */
private static final Pattern INT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\d+",
    Pattern.DOTALL);

public static int addAllIntegerOccurrences(final String input){
    int result = 0;
    if(input != null){
        final Matcher matcher = INT_PATTERN.matcher(input);
        while(matcher.find()){
            result += Integer.parseInt(matcher.group());
        }
    }
    return result;

}
```

**Test code:**

```
public static void main(final String[] args){
    System.out.println(addAllIntegerOccurrences("1,2,hello,world,3,4"));
}
```

**Output:**

> 10

**Caveats:**

This will not work if the numbers add up to anything larger than `Integer.Max_VALUE`, obviously.