# How to check if a string is parsable to float

Tags: java

How can i check if a string can be parsed to a float number?
I tried the `common-lang` `NumberUtils` library but sometimes i get wrong returns.

I don't know if that matter but my float numbers use comma seperators.

```
public TableCell call(TableColumn param) {

    return new TableCell<Course, String>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (NumberUtils.isParsable(item)) {
                if (NumberUtils.toFloat(item) >= 5) {
                    this.setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
                } else if (NumberUtils.toFloat(item) < 5) {
                    this.setTextFill(Color.RED);
                }
                setText(item);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: what about `Float()` object and catch exception if fails?

Comment: Just parse them with `Float#parseFloat` and catch the exception. Don't overthink easy tasks like this one.

Comment: i see, i had a hope for a "native"-java solution.

Comment: Why do you think this is not a native solution?

Comment: i don't think this is even a proper solution

Comment: You can use an Exception... See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133770/how-to-find-out-if-the-value-contained-in-a-string-is-double-or-not) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543729/how-to-check-that-a-string-is-parseable-to-a-double).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned before, use [`Float#parseFloat(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat-java.lang.String-) but don't forget to replace the commas:

```
try {
    float val = Float.parseFloat(string.replace(',', '.'));
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // Executed iff the string couldn't be parsed.
}
```

Inspired by [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3543749/3429133), you can also check out the corresponding [`Float#valueOf(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) if you prefer a nasty regex.

Answer (score 0):

A string can be parse to float if and only if.

All the chars in the strring are a valid chars in a float number(including decimal representations which is locale dependent)

the best way could be try to parse it forcing the code to throw an exception if something fails...

`Float#parseFloat()` will do the job in this case..