# RegEx Capture British Pound and number higher then 4

Tags: regex

I would like to capture the British pound sign and any numbers over 4.

Examples of what i would like to match:

```
£30,000
£10,000
£100,000
£10000
£12,450
£1000000
```

Examples of what i don't want to match:

```
£100
100
£1000
£1000.00
£5000
£2.20
£1
£0
```

Comment: Do you mean "british pound sign followed by at least 5 numbers (10000+)"?

Comment: What flavour of Regex are you using? What language are you calling this regex from?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295327/regex-to-parse-international-floating-point-numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
£(?=(?:\d,?){5})[\d,.]+
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eT9fZ2/4)

Comment: `1,000.00` is not valid, though. (`1,000` is 5 in length)

Comment: Strange that title says length should be 4. More clarity needed from OP I think.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, but from his examples I suppose he wants numbers that are `10000` or higher. OP needs to respond, though.

Comment: This also matches characters can it only be set to match numbers. Example £100,000blablah

Comment: thanks but one thing it should still match text text £100,000 text text > it should still match £100,000 and even when its £100,000blahblah > should still match £100,000 but not the text.

Comment: Not clear what you want. Doesn't it totally match what you said valid and invalid list in the question? If your requirement is different then why not update the question and make it clear.

Comment: I have made another update based on my understanding. See if this works for you (check new demo also).